# Windows blank screen at startup; bios freeze; restart at shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, freeze

I have some issues with my computer:

- I start the computer but nothing shows up on screen
- the computer freeze on the bios screen
- I go throught the bios screen but then I have a blank screen
- when I switch off my computer it restarts

It can take me like 10min of switching on/off to be able to boot. But when I succeed to start my computer I have no problem until I switch it off.

I have try chkdsk, memtest, remove graphic card, but that gives me nothing...

Comment: When did this start? Have you added any new hardware or recent updates that may have caused these issues?

Comment: @Aardwolf I started to have issues few months back but it's getting worse. No hardware update and no major software update. And as the issue appears even before bios screen I think it is not windows related.

Comment: I would try clearing the CMOS by removing and re-inserting the battery. If that fails, I would probably start looking at the power supply and test to see if its faulty.

Comment: I have cleared the CMOS and updated the bios and I have less freeze even if it is still not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

your booting system file are probably corrupted, try use the automatic repair tool in windows.

here an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-HKlr_3o0Q

hope it help.